# How to get from an EditPart to its Editor in Eclipse? (Eclipse plug-in development)

Tags: eclipse, editor, plugins

I am writing an eclipse plug-in that extends editor.  Inside the editor I put some EditParts.  From some of these edit parts I need a reference to their encapsulating editor (so that for example, when clicking an instance of MyEditPart, I want to programmatically  close the editor).

Please advise on the API to get from an EditPart instance to the Editor it is in.

Thanks.

Comment: The IEditorPart interface is the main abstraction for an editor, so I'm not sure there is a direct answer to your question as such.  Clarify with more information: say you navigated from the part to the thing you want; what would you then do with that?

Comment: Some examples: when the user clicks my edit part (a node in a graph shown inside the editor), the editor page where this edit part is should execute save / should close / should change from read only to writable / should show a message with the name of the contributing plug-in of the editor (like in the plug-in spy of eclipse)

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
IEditorPart editor = ((DefaultEditDomain) getViewer().getEditDomain()).getEditorPart();
```

from the EditPart.